# Как уменьшить размер ширины выпадющего списка у select? Max-width не работает

Tags: html, css

Я использую тег и хочу изменить выпадающий список select. Я действительно пробовал использовать max-width: 100px, но у меня это не работает. Как это изменить? Первая фотография - моя. Вторая картинка - это то, что я хочу сделать. Пожалуйста, помогите мне
Красный - это то, какую ширину я хочу [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Картинки прекрасны, а теперь покажите ваш код, как html, так и css.

Comment: На второй картинке не используются стандартные элементы `<select>`, `<option>`, там используются кастомные `<select>`, `<option>` элементы сделанные на JavaScript.

Comment: @Quazimorda,там просто в html select и внутри option-ы . Css никакого нет. Вторая фотка -не мой код.

Comment: @ΝNL993,спасибо большое

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.